Is it possible to use kafka transactions with RetryableTopic in spring boot?
I have a a spring boot application configured to a mongoDB database. I'm using spring libraries for kafka and mongo. I have a kafka listener that invokes a method that is annotated with Transactional. In this method I write to multiple collections and in the end send a message to a different kafka topic. If an exception is thrown then the mongo transaction manager rolls back all of the changes. I haven't configured kafka transaction manager so the message is committed.
I recently added the RetryableTopic annotation so if an exception is thrown, the consumer will invoke the logic again. This works great, still without kafka transactions.
When I tried adding the kafka transaction manager, the retry logic didn't work properly and I got an exception that said "transaction was marked as rollback only" and the message wasn't sent to the retry topic and instead entered a loop of reading the same message from the original topic.
I read this article:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/transactions.html
and stumbled upon a note that said "Non-Blocking Retries cannot combine with Container Transactions. When the listener code throws an exception, container transaction commit succeeds, and the record is sent to the retryable topic."
I don't see messages written to the retryable topic sdo i'm not sure if this applies in my case.
What am I missing or is this impossible to implement with spring's RetryableTopic?
This is a pseudocode of my listener:
public class Consumer {
    @KafkaListener(*/ configuration /*)
    @RetryableTopic(*/ configuration /*)
    public void consume(ConsumerRecord record) {
        service.foo(record)
    }

    // in a service class 
    @Transactional
    public void foo(ConsumerRecord record) {
        /* logic */
        mongoTemplate.save(object1);
        mongoTemplate.save(object2);
        kafkaTemplate.sendMessage(message);
    }
}


Thanks in advance.
